# Largest Distance of any point on $X-$ axis to Ellipse.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculation of longest distance of any point on the curve $2x^2+y^2-2x=0$ and a

point $A(a,0)$ lie on $\bf{X-axis}.$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write given equation as $\displaystyle 2\left(x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}\right)+y^2-\frac{1}{2}=0$

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{1}{2}} = 1.$ Now Let any point $\displaystyle P\left(\frac{1+\cos \theta}{2}\;,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin \theta \right)$.

lie on that Ellipse.

So $\displaystyle AP = \sqrt{\left(a-\left\{\frac{1+\cos \theta}{2}\right\}\right)^2+\frac{\sin^2 \theta }{2}} = \sqrt{a^2+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\cos^2 \theta}{4}-a(1+\cos \theta)+\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{2}}$

Now How can I Maximize It.

Help Required, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to maximize $$\left(a-\frac{1+\cos\theta}2\right)^2+\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{2}=\frac{8a^2-8a+4-(\cos\theta+2a-1)^2}4$$

i.e.,  to minimize $(\cos\theta+2a-1)^2$

Now use $-1\le\cos\theta\le1\iff2a-2\le\cos\theta+2a-1\le2a$

Comment: There is something wrong with this answer. if we take $a=2$ the maximum distance should be $2$, the distance from $A$ to the origin. But this formula gives $1$ as the largest distance.

Comment: @Lozenges, Rectified calculation. Can you please check

Comment: missing a term $cos(\theta)/2$ in the first line . it was wrong in the OP.

Comment: we want to maximize (not minimize) the distance, which means minimize $(\cos (\theta )+2a-1)^2$. What is the next step?

Comment: @Lozenges, The minimum value will depend on the value of $a$,right? If $a=1,(\cos\theta-1)^2\ge0$ If $a=4,(\cos\theta+7)^2\ge36$

Comment: OK. so the minimum value occurs when $\cos (\theta )=1-2a$ which gives $x=(1+\cos (\theta ))/2=1-a$ which is the right answer for $0\leq a\leq 1$

Comment: @Lozenges, Do you mean to say, for $a=2$(say) there can be no maximum distance?

Answer (score 1):

the square of the distance from $A(a,0)$ to a point $P(x,y)$ on the ellipse is given by

$(x-a)^2+y^2=(x-a)^2+(2x-2x^2)=$

$a^2+(1-a)^2-(x-(1-a))^2$

So the maximum occurs at $x=1-a$ 
EDIT:
the max distance $=\sqrt{a^2+(1-a)^2}$

This argument is valid only for $0\leq a\leq 1$

For $a>1$ the largest distance is $a$

For $a<0$ the largest distance is $1-a$

Answer (score -1):

Just look at the graph of ellipse which touches y-axis. The semi-major diameter is parallel to y-axis $ = \sqrt 2,$ ellipse minor diameter is $1$ . Assuming $a$ is real positive. A variable point with $ x = a $ moves on x-axis.

Due to symmetry we can say directly say without needing maxima/minima calculations:

Maximum distance is $a$ if the variable point $|x|=a>1$  is outside the ellipse on x-axis and  $ (1-a) $ if $ |a| < 1 $, inside the ellipse.

EDIT1:

To build  generality, remove intuition and fully capture all such cases where constants are appearing together and to establish a relation among them , we seek double roots/tangency/discriminant zero / for intersection of:

$$  x^2 + y^2 = R^2 , b^2 ( x- h )^2 + a^2 y^2= a^2 b^2 $$

Comment: incorrect. take $a=1/2$ the max distance is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ which does not equal $1-a$

Comment: Can change it,  it is a extremum ; I was making a point about recognizing situations avoiding jumping into  calculations